# How to get the status code of a CORS http failed preflight requets

Tags: javascript, cors, http-status-codes, preflight

Is it possible to get the error code of a failed preflight request so that I can print a meaningful error message? *(Or is there a habit of printing a static error for all failed preflight requests no matter the code?)*

Clearly, the status code `401` is printed to the console, but the error handler or a `.catch()` statement only receive the error object thrown.
[image: with preflight]

If I remove the header that triggers the preflight, I get to handle the response myself and I can extract the status code.
[image: without preflight]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it isn't.

If the status code of the preflight response is not 200, then the Same Origin Policy will prevent any information about the response from being extracted from it.

I've just finished setting up a web API to always return 200 OK status for OPTIONS requests for this reason.

Comment: That's not entirely correct. One necessary requirement for preflight to succeed is that [the preflight response have an _ok status_ (i.e. a status in the 2xx range)](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-responses). 200 is one such status, but obviously not the only one.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not. All `fetch` returns is a `TypeError` with message "Failed to fetch".

```
> fetch('https://stackexchange.com/404').then(x => console.info(x), error => console.error(error))
× TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

I tried to manually send another preflight-request and grab the response code of that.

```
> fetch('https://stackexchange.com/404', { method: 'OPTIONS' }).then(x => console.info(x), error => console.error(error))
× TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

But that just triggers another preflight and still doesn't let me at the actual failed request.